# node-schedule not working with express app

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, node-schedule

I'm trying to add a scheduler to my express typescript app and my code is as follows:

app.ts (The port and host are defined)

```
import express from "express";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { testTask } from "./task/updatePairsTask";

import router from "./api/router";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/", router);

const httpServer = createServer(app).listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
  console.log(`Started server at ${HOST}:${PORT}`);
});
```

And I have my job defined here: in updatePairsTask.ts

```
import schedule from "node-schedule";

export const testTask = schedule.scheduleJob("/1 * * * * *", () => {
  console.log("Words");
});
```

I assume this should make the scheduler print every one second to the console, but nothing seems to printing once the app starts beyond the "Started server" message.

Could you help with the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try with `*/1 * * * * *`

Comment: @HarshitRastogi, sorry doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) package to manipulate Cron tasks in very easy way.

You can use [this](https://crontab.guru/) website to get cron schedule expression.

```
import express from "express";
import { createServer } from "http";
import { testTask } from "./task/updatePairsTask";
// import CronJob from "cron"; // npm i cron
const CronJob = require("cron").CronJob

import router from "./api/router";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use("/", router);

const job = new CronJob({
    cronTime: '* * * * * *',
    onTick: function () {
        testTask()
    },
    start: false,
    timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'
})

job.start()

const httpServer = createServer(app).listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
  console.log(`Started server at ${HOST}:${PORT}`);
  // you can also put job.start() here.
});
```